# How to get numerical solutions for Geodesic path using numerical Metric in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, differential-geometry, computational-physics, geodesics

I have question regarding numerical method to calculate geodesic path, when the analytic form of the metric is unknown, please.

Suppose that we have a black-box at hand that can show us a measurement value for the metric $ds$ line element every time we move a short distance in space.

For space coordinates $(x,y,z)$, the geodesic path from $[x_1, y_1, z_1]$ to $[z_2, y_2, z_2]$ can be 'guessed' by for instance starting first with a linear interpolation along all the 3 coordinate bases, then iterating the guess over and over while trying to minimize the sum over all ds.

But when one of the variables is $t$, I am unsure if this changes anything, or places any new restrictions on the algorithms normally usable for $(x,y,z)$?

For example, suppose that the black-box is secretly (unbeknownst to us) outputting:

$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2Gm}{r}\right)dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{\left(1-\frac{2Gm}{r}\right)} + r^2 d \Omega^2$$

**Are there any special restrictions imposed by physics on minimizing sum of ds over a path from $[t_1, r_1, \theta_1, \phi_1]$ to $[t_2, r_2, \theta_2, \phi_2]$? In particular, can $t_1$ and $t_2$ be any values, or only a restricted set of values are allowed in this case?**

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about whether there's an equation that a geodesic must satisfy but any other non-geodesic curve doesn't? Yes there is, it is called the geodesic equation

Comment: @ Prof thank you for answering! Yes I was wondering if, given only the numerical values of metric at the different coordinates, but with the function itself hidden from us (ie. all differential geometry tools denied to us, including the equation of geodesics), can we come up with the correct geodesic path using only numerical methods in this case? We might imagine that the source of the metric is a gigantic star-sized mass in the exact shape of the Statue of Liberty, then the analytic expression for the metric can probably never be derived no matter how hard we try to, is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: still not clear what you are asking. You can use ordinary numerical methods for solving differential equations such as e.g. Runge-Kutta to solve the geodesic equation

Comment: @Prof Thank you. Yes, i was aiming at the numerical solution. Thanks for pointing out the Runge-Kutta method!

Comment: is there any special constraints for t because it represents time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a second-order differential equation, you need initial conditions (coordinates and velocities) and then you can use numerical methods to evolve this forward or backward in the evolution parameter.

Conceptually the easiest way would be to numerically integrate:
$$ x(\tau + \Delta \tau) \approx x(\tau) + v(\tau) \Delta \tau, $$
$$ v(\tau + \Delta \tau) \approx v(\tau) + F(x(\tau), v(\tau)) \Delta \tau $$

where $F$ is the function that defines your differential equation:
$$ \ddot{x} = F(x, \dot{x}). $$

In practice, accumulating precision loss comes from the fact that in the method above we've taken $F$ at point $\tau$ and not somewhere in between of $\tau$ and $\tau + \Delta \tau$. A better method that avoids much of this loss is [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

The geodesic equation is precisely a second-order differential equation, so all of the above applies:
$$ \ddot{x}^{\mu} = - \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu} \dot{x}^{\alpha} \dot{x}^{\beta}. $$

You can take this exact form and reconstruct the parametric solution using numerical methods, but there's a better way. The evolution parameter in the form of the geodesic equation above is the proper time $\tau$. Hovewer, for most practical implications, we're interested in how the trajectory of the test particle depends on the coordinate time $t = x^0$.

You could first solve the equation numerically for $x^{\mu}(\tau)$ and then construct the function $x^k(x^0)$ using interpolation, however, in situations where proper and coordinate times are greatly out of sync (such as e.g. in the vicinity of the event horizon), you will lose precision.

A better way is to change the form of the geodesic equation first (on a whiteboard or on a piece of paper), to change its form such that the evolution parameter is $t = x^0$ and not $\tau$. This is not super hard to do, but it is a slightly nontrivial calculation.

Here I'll draft the strategy for you, but I expect you to do the calculation yourself (feel free to ask a homework-and-exercise question if you are stuck).

The calculation roughly goes as follows. First, note that for any quantity $Q$,
$$ \frac{d Q}{d \tau} = \frac{d Q}{dt} \frac{dt}{d \tau}. $$

The quantity
$$ \gamma = \frac{dt}{d \tau} $$
will obviously play a major role in the calculation, along with its first derivative
$$ \frac{d \gamma}{d \tau} = \gamma \frac{d \gamma}{dt}, $$
as is evident from the zero'th component geodesic equation (with $\ddot{x^0}$).

We now rewrite the spatial components of the geodesic equation such that only the coordinate time derivatives, $\gamma$ and $\dot{\gamma}$ are allowed.

Finally, we use the time component of the geodesic equation to fix a relationship between $\gamma$ and $\dot{\gamma}$ and plug it back in the spatial components. This will eliminate both $\gamma$ and $\dot{\gamma}$ from the equation, leaving us with the desired form of the geodesic equation on $x^k(t)$.

Then use Runge-Kutta or your other favorite numerical method to solve that and reconstruct $x^k(t)$. You'll need to know the components of the affine connection, but those are trivially computable from the metric:
$$ \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu} = \frac{g^{\mu \nu}}{2} \left( \frac{\partial g_{\nu \beta}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} + \frac{\partial g_{\alpha \nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}} - \frac{\partial g_{\alpha \beta}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right), $$

and you can take the partial derivatives in the formula above numerically by approximating them with finite differences.

Comment: @ Prof Legolasov thank you! I have come across the geodesic equations and have calculated with the Christoffel symbols, but I don't feel I fully understand the definition of geodesics. Is it correct if I define geodesics as follows: In 3D, a small step forward, let's call it ds, along a manifold is a geodesic path if and only if it always traces a straight lane on the small planar surface for sufficiently small ds. Is this a fair intuitive definition? Then, what is the correct geodesic path to take as we reach an edge on a 3D cube shape, and transition to a different face on it? Thank you.

Comment: @James that sounds over complicated. Geodesics are simply locally shortest paths in a Riemannian manifold. Fix two points $a$ and $b$ and connect them with a path $x(\tau)$. Your path is a geodesic if and only if it solves the variational problem with the action functional equal to the length of the path $S[x] = \intop_0^1 d \tau \sqrt{g_{ab} \frac{dx^a}{d \tau} \frac{dx^b}{d \tau}}$, with Dirichlet boundary conditions $x(0) = a$, $x(1) = b$.

Comment: @James the Euler-Lagrange equation is a bit complex, but it simplifies a lot when you choose the (apriori arbitrary) parameter $\tau$ to measure the length along the geodesic. In that case you get $\ddot{x}^{\mu} = - \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta} \dot{x}^{\alpha} \dot{x}^{\beta}$, the geodesic equation (try deriving this yourself if you're proficient in variational calculus, it is nontrivial but not extremely hard either). For a pseudo-Riemannian manifold timelike geodesics actually maximize (and not minimize) proper time along the curve, but the variational equation is exactly the same.

Comment: @ Prof thank you. My background is in discrete math and computing, so I can do problems/calculations with infinitesimals but it's somehow not naturally intuitive for me :) Regarding S[x] above, for the case of geodesics around the edge of a 3D cube face, I have wondered about what the path should be the geodesic line transitioning from one face to the next... What is the predicted path (angle change) traced by the geodesic line transitioning between cube faces using S[x] above?

Comment: @James geodesic have absolutely nothing to do with the global properties of your manifold. They are local minima, that is, you should be able to tell if a curve is a geodesic by looking at arbitrary short (but finite) parts of it. For a surface of a cube, geodesics are straight lines on its sides, because you didn’t give the cube any curvature

Comment: @ Prof so as the geodesic line transitions from one face to the next, is there a differential geometric definition for what the geodesic line should be, or is it undefined along the edges of the cube?

Comment: @James think of an unwrapping of your cube on a plane where both sides are shared. The unwrapping is flat so the geodesic is just a straight line. That includes the edge where the two sides of the cube meet

Comment: @ Prof thanks very much, it's been very helpful for me!